# Как создать и обучить нейронную сеть на java?

Tags: java, база-данных, нейронные-сети

помогите с созданием нейронки. В них пока чайник. Хочу чтобы она выводила значение от 1.0 до 0.0 на выходе, при подаче на входные нейроны около сотни параметров. Есть база данных нескольких тысяч вариаций параметров с ответами. Вроде как сеть прямого распространения мне подойдет. Может посоветуете какую-нибудь библиотеку для создания и работы с нейронной сетью, а также мне нужно ее как-то интегрировать в приложение. Она ведь сможет себя сама обучить по этой базе данных? И сколько примерно понадобится нейронов со слоями?

Comment: Сейчас, на самом деле, не проблема найти ресурсы на эту тему. Даже ресурсы (видео) навроде "Нейронные сети за пару секунд" вам подойдут. Библиотек много; можно даже самому написать что-нибудь из готовых кусков. Насчёт количества нейронов следует описать задачу, можно "пирамидой" 100 - 80 - 60 - x (1) или "стенкой" 100 - 120 - 120 - x

Comment: 1. Может этот [вариант](http://www.jooneworld.com/) подойдет? 2. А вообще вот, [подборка](https://bookflow.ru/nejrosetevoe-programmnoe-obespechenie/).